# multiple sites use one apache solr server

Tags: 7, search

I am a beginner of using Apache Solr. I made a mistake two weeks ago.
I link two of my sites to one Apache Solr server. One is dev site, another is live site. There are some different data between these two sites. But I forgot to set "read only" on dev site.

Right now, everything is messed up. The dev site data shows on live site. How can I fix this? I tried to fix, but still no luck.

My fix steps:

- Download [Apache Solr Multiple Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch) on my dev site.
- Set Apache Solr Search index access as "Read only"
- Reindex all queue on my live site
- Wait two days
- Check the live site, still messy

I really appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apachesolr_multisite allows you to tenant multiple Drupal sites in one Solr search core, allowing searching across sites, or on single sites, but it must be configured. Go to admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings, click "Edit" on the Solr search environment, and examine the settings at the bottom of the form:

[image]

These must be configured properly for your use case.

Comment: I just saw one site. That's weird. But I think your answer must work fine.

Comment: Since two sites have already mess up. Do you have any idea whether I can make them work as usual again? What do I need to do for fixing this?

Comment: You can delete the indexes and re-index.