# how to retrieve data for apache solr

Tags: 7, search

I am using apache solr 3.x .
Right now, I mixed the data from my two websites into one solr by mistake. I set one solr on the first website server and set another website's Apache Solr search to link to this server. I don't know they will mess up when I set this. But right now, the first website doesn't add any data into the solr, and all the data from the other website can add the data to the solr.

Is there anyway that I can retrieve each website data to make them show in the correct position?

Comment: Solr indexes are designed to be transient - delete the data, re-index the site whose data you want to be in there, job done

Comment: what if I just re-index the site? does this work?

Comment: Without clearing the existing data? Doubt it

Comment: Thank you for your help. But right now, I think some nodes index are overridden. I don't know why. Cause some of the products only be showed once. I think if the index are doubled, the products should be showed in two position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Apache Solr Multisite search https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch This is the proper way to have multiple sites sharing one index. You can search all sites or single sites.

Comment: More info here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205857/multiple-sites-use-one-apache-solr-server/205871

Comment: I used this module after I noticed the site mess up. I think it would be fine if I used it at the very beginning, but right now, it doesn't work well.

Comment: Do I need to add this module in both of my website?

Comment: Yes, it must be installed on all Drupal sites that are in the same Solr index.